# How can I use auto-import component in render function of Vue3(Vite) without explicitly importing component?

Tags: vuejs3

How can I use auto-import component in render function of Vue3(Vite) without annotate registering component ?

I can use jsx to dynamically render the auto-import custom component that I want without explicitly importing it in Vue2(Webpack4), like below,it works well:

```
export default {
    ......
    render (h) {
        let { props, attrs, extraRender, htmlTag, on } = this.data
        return (
            <htmlTag
                props={{
                    ...props
                }}
                value={this.value}
                attrs={attrs}
            >
            </htmlTag>
        )
    },
    .....
```

But I don’t know how can I dynamically render my auto-import component without explicitly importing it in Vue3(Vite)? like below:

```
import { h } from "vue";
export default {
  props: {
    params: Object,
  },
  setup(props: { params: { tag: string; props: any } }) {
    const params = props.params;

    return () => [h(params.tag)];
  },
};
```

Yeah, it is clear that if I give a string to function h it will treat it as a native html tag after execting, but I can't explicitly import component here.
I just want to know what I should do to get the same result as what I did in Vue2(webpack).

I’m very appreciative of your help!

Comment: I realized that I made a mistake. In Vue2 (Webpack), I was using Vue.use("my-ui-component") to get a component by passing a string variable at template tag, and I should be using app.use(my-ui-component) to import the complete module and pass a string variable to the template tag in Vue3(Vite), in order to achieve the same result. Actually, I had a misconception about web apps. I can't dynamically import the component I want at runtime by async because it is determined during build time, unless I import it over the network.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an equivalent of what you had in Vue2 as of now, which is why people seem to have made extra plugins to achieve this.

[unplugin-auto-import](https://github.com/antfu/unplugin-auto-import) seems like a valid one, or the underlying package [unimport](https://www.npmjs.com/package/unimport), although you should verify them yourself if you want to use them.

Unfortunately, I can't think of any built-in solutions, as I guess is what you actually wanted. The plugins have quite a lot of downloads, so maybe it will be added in the future.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! :) I am using both “unplugin-auto-import” and “unplugin-vue-components” in my project. The plugin “unplugin-vue-components” seems to do what I want, but it only can identify the component in the template or HTML tag in the render function without explicitly importing it. However, if I pass its name to the render tag, it will not transform its string variable name to the corresponding component. I’m looking for a solution to resolve this issue. If I find one, I will share it with you. Thanks!!!